# Is there a way to have jQuery expand across multiple DIVs?

Tags: jquery, transition

Is there a way to get jQuery to work in the following way?

I need to have a 3 by 3 grid of images, once clicked they will open a div that covers the grid. So if you clicked the top left image the div would slide left to right and top to bottom. If you clicked the middle image it would slide out in all directions.

Does anyone know of a generic method using .this to minimize code? Thanks in advance

Comment: if you give some example then it will be easy that you want to achieve.

Comment: give the html og your basic image grid. I'll try to help you.

Comment: Like the effect  at http://www.notonebit.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute position all 9 images within the container div, then use jQuery's animate() to expand them as needed.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gGc5K/

JavaScript portion:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "z-index": 1
    }).animate({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "120px",
        height: "120px"
    }, "4s");
});
```

Comment: So I used `td`s for the example, because they seemed uniquely convenient for putting in a 3x3 grid.  Any tag (including `img`) should work fine, though, perhaps with slightly more verbose CSS.

Comment: Cheers, and I guess then changing the z-index back to 0 with js would work to hide again?

Comment: No.  Changing the z-index back to 0 will make it possible for the other images to cover it up.  To put it back where it was, you'll have to animate it back to its original position (or if you don't mind it just jumping back, you could set its style attribute to "").  You should also set the z-index back to zero, but at the end of the animation - the 4th parameter to animate() will be useful for that.

Comment: It's actually possible to do this with CSS alone, if you want to look into CSS animations and the :focus pseudo-selector.

Comment: Nice, sorry to be a real pain I'm not near my laptop. The content of the expanding div is not the same as the image, what would I need to change in the js to animate the next div after each image?

Comment: Animating $(this).next("div") instead of $(this) would be the main thing.  You'll also need to position the div in the place you want the animation to start from (possibly in the .css() call).